# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

it says that   `const id = data[0];` is the one that's causing the error.

My data was stored in a location.state since this was taken from a row of the previous page. And data is stored as an array.

This is the data in a JSON object:

```
[
  "DgduuIHAf1wc2txlaK86",
  "Item1",  
];
```

These are the codes:

```
const Edit = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const data = location.state;
  const id = data[0];
  const [productName, setProductName] = useState(data[1]);
  

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {;
      const Ref = firestore.collection("products").doc(id);
      const res = Ref.set(
        {
          productName,
        },
        { merge: true }
      );
      alert("Successfully updated");
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Container>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <FormControl>
            <TextField
              id="input"
              margin="dense"
              type="text"
              label="Product Name"
              value={productName}
              color="secondary"
              fullWidth
              onChange={(e) => setProductName(e.target.value)}
            />

            <Button
              type="submit"
            >
              Update
            </Button>
          </FormControl>
        </form>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Edit;
```

It does save whatever input I have in those fields in the firestore, however, after submitting it, it will display this error: How can I fix this?

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: Log out the value of `location.state` before you attempt to access it. I think you'll find the `data` property is undefined.

Comment: console.log of location.state is the same with the data JSON object from above

Comment: Try this `const { data } = location.state;`

Comment: @net.uk.sweet it return an undefined

Answer (score 0):

Probably `.. = location.state;` return undefined.

Comment: Show location object.
`const location = useLocation();
 console.log(location)
 const data = location.state;`

Comment: @JenJennie Could you please tell us the output of the previous comment, so we can help you further? Thank you.